# When opening Excel workbook using VBA how to make the open workbook the active window?

Tags: excel, focus, vba

I'm using a an xlsm file form that calls up a second form to ask the user to select which workbook to open. The VBA code will then open that workfile. However, I'm finding that in Office 2016, the file opens behind the original xlsm file. That is, it will not become the active window. I can use Alt+Tab to go to the open file, but the file will not interact with my keystrokes or mouse clicks until I Alt+Tab to activate the originating xlsm file. Then when I reactive the VBA-opened file, I can interact with it. That is, the file that VBA opened will not become active until I touch base back with the workfile that has the VBA code. I've tried a series of activeworkbooks, application.activewindow commands to activate the opened workbook to no avail.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
Private Sub btn_select_Click()
' User clicks on select. If a subcategory is selected open the file and stop program. If not repopulate sub-category
    If IsNull(lst_subcategories) Or lst_subcategories = "" Then
        lst_subcategories.Clear
        Call populate_data
    Else   ' open file and unload form (End)
        If lst_datacategories <> "Tourism" Then
            str_filetoopen = "I:\Bureau-Work\Data System\" & lst_datacategories & "\" & lst_subcategories & ".xlsx"    ' May need to be F: drive
        Else
            str_filetoopen = "I:\Bureau-Work\Data System\" & lst_subcategories & "\" & lst_subcategories & ".xlsx"    ' May need to be F: drive
        End If

        On Error Resume Next      ' drive or file may not be available.  If so error and retain from
          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(str_filetoopen)
          If wb Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "I: Drive or Retrieve File is Not Accessible"
            GoTo handle    ' retains frm_editData
          End If
          Workbooks(wb).Activate
          ActiveWindow.Visible = True
        End     'exit all macros and forms once successfully loading file
    End If
handle:
End Sub
```

The "Workbooks(wb).Activate" and "Activewindow.visible=True" commands are attempts to set the new workbook window as the active window. To the best of my knowledge, this does not happen in Office 2013, but may be peculiar to Office 2016.

Comment: select a cell/range/sheet in the new workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try:

```
wb.activate
```

Works for me

Comment: Thanks Kellsens. That seemed to work, but I wonder what's the difference between that command and my `Workbooks(wb).Activate` command. It is not setting the focus on the open worksheet though, but at least I can interact with it.

Comment: Workbooks(<index>).activate is the correct form to use. It will work if you use like dis Workbooks(wb.name).Activate
To set focus to a worksheet use wb.worksheets(<name of your worksheet>).activate

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the end of your VBA script:

> ```
> Application.SendKeys ("%{TAB}")
> ```

It will try to do an Alt-Tab to switch windows, and then hopefully that'll solve your issue.

Comment: Namkce, thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, that appeared to have no impact on the outcome.  I still have to gain focus of the program xlsm file before I can gain focus on the opened file.